# Get OneSignal UserID after subscribe

Tags: push-notification, notifications, onesignal

I'm using OneSignal to get notifications, so according to docs I made my SDK code like this:

```
<script src="https://cdn.onesignal.com/sdks/OneSignalSDK.js" async></script>
<script>
var OneSignal = window.OneSignal || [];
    OneSignal.push(["init", {
      appId: "myappID",
      safari_web_id: "myID",
      autoRegister: false,
      promptOptions: {
            /* My prompt options */
       },
       welcomeNotification: {
            //my options
       },
       notifyButton: {
        enable: true,
        showCredit: false,
        prenotify: true,
        position: 'bottom-left',
        text: {
            /*My text options */
        },
        colors: { // My custom colors
        }
      }
    }]);

    OneSignal.push(function(){
        OneSignal.showHttpPrompt();

        OneSignal.getUserId().then(function(userId){
            console.log("OneSignal User ID:", userId);
        });
    });
</script>
```

It works great showing slideshow prompt message, but after subscribe I need to refresh the website to get UserID in console. How can I modify this code function to get userID in console immediately after subscribe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a listener for the subscription change event. Otherwise the getUserId call will trigger before the user has accepted the subscription. This is working for me:

```
var OneSignal = window.OneSignal || [];

OneSignal.push(function() {
  OneSignal.on('subscriptionChange', function (isSubscribed) {
    console.log("The user's subscription state is now:",isSubscribed);
      OneSignal.push(function() {
        OneSignal.getUserId(function(userId) {
          console.log("OneSignal User ID:", userId);
        });
      });
    });
  });

  OneSignal.push(["init", {
    appId: "myappID",
    safari_web_id: "myID",
    autoRegister: false,
    promptOptions: {
        /* My prompt options */
    },
    welcomeNotification: {
        //my options
    },
    notifyButton: {
      enable: true,
      showCredit: false,
      prenotify: true,
      position: 'bottom-left',
      text: {
        /*My text options */
     },
     colors: { // My custom colors
     }
   }
}]);
```

Answer (score 2):

> As of new version V.16

````
            window.OneSignalDeferred = window.OneSignalDeferred || [];
            OneSignalDeferred.push(function (OneSignal) {
                OneSignal.init({
                    appId:app_id,
                });
                OneSignal.User.PushSubscription.addEventListener("change", function (event) {
                    console.log("event");
                    console.log(event);
                    if (event.current.id) {
                        //send data to server 
                        let data = {
                            player_id: event.current.id,
                            user_id: "{{user.id}}",
                        }
                        axios.post(
                                "{% url 'notifications:save_player_id' %}",
                                data, {
                                    headers: {
                                        "X-CSRFToken": "{{ csrf_token }}"
                                    }
                                })
                            .then(function (response) {}, 5000);
                    }


                });
            });```
````